# Accessing Network Link layers through Google Earth API

Tags: arcgis-server, google-earth, kmz

When creating a Network Link, in ArcGIS Manager, I am able to add multiple layers to the KMZ. Is there a way to access each of the layers separately using the Google Earth Plugin API?